# I am concerned about a question and one of the answers but am not sure about arguing on the site

Tags: discussion, etiquette

The Facebook account creation answer has a point of view I STRONGLY disagree with. Teaching a child to break the rules is not a good idea, imo.

I have stated that opinion in my answer, but would like to tell the person who says FB's age requirement is a stupid, old person's idea, that they are incorrect. I can be polite, but am sure to start a discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely not the place to have that argument. You have your perspective, the other person has theirs. Neither of you can tell the other that they are wrong.

It would not help anyone for you to say they are incorrect - and would likely just lead to them telling you that you are incorrect.

You can post an answer with your opinion in it, as you have done, and people can up or down vote as they see fit.

(In terms of wider perspective, I think both answers are flawed - I didn't let my kids have a facebook profile until they were 13 despite all their friends having them, but this was not because of Facebook's rules specifically)

Comment: I thought discussion was not what this site was about, but did want to check. That is not a complaint, but as I am used to other sites, it does take getting used to. Thanks Rory.

Comment: Sure - one of the interesting things that does come out is how the majority of readers feel (based on votes) - occasionally you get results you wouldn't expect. We are a bit looser about discussion here in Meta (we even have the discussion tag) and in [chat] we can talk about things easily :-)

Comment: I looked at your link, but don't really get it. I will, but I guess I need to ask more questions. Do I just click on a box?

Comment: Ahh - try http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/parenting - that takes you directly to the chat room